# Parameters at Class' Initialization in VBA

Tags: vba

Is it possible to pass parameters to a class at initialization time, as done in object-oriented languages ​​such as Java, where you can create parameterized constructors. The event `Class_Initialize ()` does not allow me to enter parameters. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not do such a thing. Only two step workaround could do the thing: 1st step- initialization, 2nd step- calling method or property which pass any parameter.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately you cannot have parameterized constructors, the closest alternative is a factory pattern:

```
public function CreateMyClass(i as integer, str as string) As cMyClass
    
    Set CreateMyClass = New cMyClass

    '// a method within class to accept constructor-like args;
    CreateMyClass.ctor i, str

    '// alternatively setup via properties
    CreateMyClass.Prop = str

end function

...

dim myClass As cMyClass
set myClass = CreateMyClass(123, "Hello")
```

Answer (score 2):

make your own on to wrap around that?

```
Sub new_myClass(str1 as String, int1 as Integer) As myClass
  Dim mc As myClass
  mc.int_attribute = int1
  mc.str_attribute = str1
  '...
  return mc
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible, the constructor is called "sub new" and you can provide parameters.

Comment: Providing some example code would make this answer much more helpful. Please [edit] your question to include more detail.